# How to simplify this code using decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to simplify the code by finding a good place to use `decltype`.
Also is there a place where `auto` wouldn’t work in this code?

```
 map<int, float> m = build_map();
 std::pair<int, int> scaling_factor(2, 3);
 std::pair<int, int>* scaled_array = new std::pair<int, int>[m.size()];

 int i(0);
 for(map<int, float>::iterator it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); it++, i++)
 {
   std::pair<int, int> tmp = *it;
   tmp.first*= caling_factor.first;
   tmp.second*= scaling_factor.second;
   scaled_array[i] = tmp;
 }
```

Comment: `map<int, auto>` doesn't work, at least not in C++11, anyway.

Comment: Yes, it works in C++98, I am meant to make use of decltype and rewrite the code.

Comment: I was answering your second question, "Also is there a place where auto wouldn’t work in this code?" It was just an example of something that didn't work in C++11.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to simplify your code using `auto` keyword.

The first that comes to mind is a range-for loop:

```
std::map<int, float> m = build_map();
std::pair<int, int> scaling_factor(2, 3);
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> scaled_array;

scaled_array.reserve(m.size());

for (auto &el : m) {
    scaled_array.emplace_back(
        el.first * scaling_factor.first,
        el.second * scaling_factor.second
    );
}
```

Comment: I would have said for vector declaration... if pair has matched map one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplification:

```
auto m = build_map();
const std::pair<int, int> scaling_factor(2, 3);
auto* scaled_array = new std::pair<int, int>[m.size()];

int i(0);
for (std::pair<int, float> copy : m) // copy and conversion
{
    copy.first *= caling_factor.first;
    copy.second *= scaling_factor.second;
    scaled_array[i++] = copy;
}
```

`std::transform` seems also a good improvement.

Comment: @rustyx: indeed, fixed by replacing `auto` (which is `std::pair<const int, float>`) by `std::pair<int, float>`.

Answer (score 0):

or further:

```
auto m = build_map();
auto scaling_factor = std::make_pair(2, 3);
std::vector<scaling_factor> scaled_array;
```

Actually somebody changed this to a vector, so the original:

```
auto scaled_array = new decltype(scaling_factor)[m.size()];
```

But you need to decide if that is more readable, especially as it obfuscates that the `.second` has changed type between the map and the array.